# Android ExpandableList with static items/without adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

In my app, there is an Activity which contains a lot of Views (editText-fields,...). Because of that the screen is too small to fit all the views. Therefore I want to use an ExpandableList which contains all the views semantically grouped (as Layouts) to list items.

Is there an easy way to get this done? Implementing an Adapter seems to be a bit complicated, regarding that the list should only contain "static" views.

Something like this would be nice:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ExpandableListView lv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.explist);
  lv.addItem(findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutitemone);
  lv.addItem(findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutitemtwo);
  EditText et = (EditText) lv.getItem(1).findViewById(R.id.etBirthdate);
  et.setText("01.01.1970");
  (....)
}
```

Comment: using adapters is actually easier, if you don't you may end up writing the same code you would have written in the adapter + some extras (like for-loops). Just find a good template for a custom adapter, and change what you have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written an own adapter extending BaseExpandableListAdapter. In the adapter i keep instances of the layouts to display as class variables - not the best solution regarding performance, but a convenient solution. As there is only a fixed short number of items to display, the performance issue won't bother much.

Answer (score 0):

To map static data you can use [SimpleExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html). The API demos has [an example of how to use it](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList3.html).

Comment: The SimpleExpandableListAdapter only accepts Data (like Strings, everything one can put into a TextView) to display. I want to display complete Layouts including EditTexts, RadioButtons, and so on.

Comment: @user1437307 Then you've have to extend `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. It's not difficult at all though it may seem intimidating if you've not done it before.